# How to put output in textarea? (JAVASCRIPT)

Tags: javascript

So this is my coding, I really hope you guys can help me. I'm trying to put the result of the calculation in the textarea but I just don't know how and what should I use.

I have been trying to use span ID and getElementById. I think the language that I used is the most basic language.

```html
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function bmicalc ()
{
 var fheight = document.form1.fheight.value;
 var fweight = document.form1.fweight.value;
 var result;
 
 result = fweight / ( fheight * fheight);

 return result;
}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<p align="center"><b><font size="4">BMI CALCULATOR</font><b></p>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table border="0" align="center">

<tr>
<td>Height:</td>
<td><input name="fheight" type="text" size="15"> meters
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Weight:</td>
<td><input name="fweight" type="text" size="15"> kilograms
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get result" onclick="bmicalc()">
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<textarea name="result" cols="30" rows="5" >
Your BMI is <result>
</textarea>
</tr>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function bmicalc ()
{
    var fheight = document.form1.fheight.value;
    var fweight = document.form1.fweight.value;
    var result;

    result = fweight / ( fheight * fheight);

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;
}
```

Comment: It should, paste it in your console for testing purpose

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the value of the textarea to the result

You can do this by adding this code just before returning your result value

```
 document.getElementById('result-textarea').value = 'Your BMI result' + result;
```

And also changing the text area to

```
<textarea id="result-textarea" name="result" cols="30" rows="5" >

</textarea>
```

Additionally I would like to point out that unless you're using some type of framework or library `<result>` is not a valid html element.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function bmicalc()
{
 var fheight = document.form1.fheight.value;
 var fweight = document.form1.fweight.value;
 var result;
 
 result = fweight / ( fheight * fheight);

    document.getElementById('result').value = "Your BMI is " + result;
    
 return result;
}
```

```html
<p align="center"><b><font size="4">BMI CALCULATOR</font><b></p>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table border="0" align="center">

<tr>
<td>Height:</td>
<td><input name="fheight" type="text" size="15"> meters
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Weight:</td>
<td><input name="fweight" type="text" size="15"> kilograms
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get your result!" onclick="bmicalc()">
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<textarea name="result" cols="30" rows="5" id="result"></textarea>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifi you `bmicalc`

```
function bmicalc ()
{
    var fheight = document.form1.fheight.value;
    var fweight = document.form1.fweight.value;
    var result;

    result = fweight / ( fheight * fheight);
    document.form1.result.value = "Your BMI is " + result;
    return result;
}
```